# How to invoke a method accepting linq expression arguments

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6

hi this is my method which exists as part of a generic entity framework repository class.

```
public IList<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
        {
            List<T> list;

            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = Context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            list = dbQuery
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList<T>();
            return list;
        }
```

I need to call the method via reflection and this is what I have done so far.

```
using (var ctx = (DbContext)Activator.CreateInstance(dbContextType))
            {
                ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                var curEntityPI = ctx.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pr => pr.Name == "Worker").First();
                var curEntityType = curEntityPI.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                var set = ctx.Set(curEntityType);
                Type generic = typeof(DataAccess.Repository.EF.dEfDataRepository<,>);
                Type[] typeArgs = {curEntityType, dbContextType};
                Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                MethodInfo methodInfo = constructed.GetMethod("GetAll");

                object repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed, new object[] { ctx });
                var result = methodInfo.Invoke(repositoryInstance,new object[] { });
            }
```

I know I need to change the parameter array in methodInfo.Invoke, but for test purposes say it was just an empty linq expression or the equivalent of this when called statically ..

```
WorkerRepository workerRepositoryInstance = new
WorkerRepository<Worker,MyDbContext>(ctx);
List<Worker> workers = workerRepositoryInstance.GetAll().ToList();
```

How would I supply the correct parameter in methodInfo.Invoke()

I am doing this because I need to work with a dbcontext and entities which are in an external dll and can't add a reference to this in my application project. My application needs to able reference the 'satellite' assembly in a way that different deployments of the application can access different versions of the data provider dll.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use the `Expression.*()` methods to build an expression tree.

Comment: What's the actual question? To avoid exception in what you've done so far?

Comment: For now yes, the new object[] { } is creating an exception so I just want to get as far through reflection as the equivalent static code in the last block (assuming I typed it correctly as in actual fact I have instantiated my repositories elsewhere slightly differently through DI) i.e get some results. Beyond that though I would like to get some understanding on how I would invoke this method with a sample expression as I have not done a lot with reflection, or not also combining linq and generics. For this I won't have direct access to any types in the assembly only entity names i.e "Worker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to create dynamically an empty array of `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

You can use [`Array.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that:

```
var navigationPropertyType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(curEntityType, typeof(object)));

var navigationProperties = Array.CreateInstance(navigationPropertyType, 0);

var result = methodInfo.Invoke(repositoryInstance, new object[] { navigationProperties });
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ivan that sorted my immediate problem. Do you have any good references for creating linq expressions? Or know what the best terms I could search around myself. I thought Lambda, linq func expression yes? Thanks anyway all the best.

Comment: `Expression.Parameter`, `Expression.PropertyOrField` and `Expression.Lambda` should be sufficient for creating `Include` expressions. For reference, I don't know - I have a lot of SO posts in that area, but all they come from self learning and experimenting.